# ACPI Error: Field [CDW3] at 96 exceeds Buffer

Tags: linux-kernel, fedora, acpi

I've just installed on an old HP ML310 G5 box Fedora 25 Server edition from the current ISO. It boots with the installation kernel - 4.8.6-300. I see in dmesg the errors below, but still it boots.

```
[    0.033000] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU            3065  @ 2.33GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0xf, stepping: 0xb)
[    0.033000] Performance Events: PEBS fmt0+, Core2 events, Broken BIOS detected, complain to your hardware vendor.
[    0.033000] [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 186 is 43003c)
[    0.033000] Intel PMU driver.
...
[    0.678420] ACPI: Thermal Zone [THM0] (8 C)
[    0.678473] ERST: Failed to get Error Log Address Range.
[    0.678578] GHES: APEI firmware first mode is enabled by WHEA _OSC.
...
[    7.356291] iTCO_wdt: Found a ICH9R TCO device (Version=2, TCOBASE=0x0960)
[    7.356313] watchdog: iTCO_wdt: cannot register miscdev on minor=130 (err=-16).
[    7.356453] watchdog: iTCO_wdt: a legacy watchdog module is probably present.
[    7.356823] iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=30 sec (nowayout=0)
...
[   12.411314] audit: type=1305 audit(1492254455.147:78): audit_pid=800 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=1
[   12.804386] Raw EDID:
[   12.804433]      00 00 00 00 00 00 3f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   12.804519]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   12.804613]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   12.804718]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   12.804803]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   12.804888]      ff ff ff 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   12.804973]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   12.805065]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   12.833820] EDID block is all zeroes
[   12.862313] EDID block is all zeroes
[   12.890773] Raw EDID:
[   12.890817]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   12.890902]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   12.890987]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   12.891081]      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[   12.891166]      00 00 00 00 00 7f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   12.891263]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   12.891364]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   12.891449]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   12.891538] radeon 0000:01:02.0: VGA-1: EDID block 0 invalid.
```

after I did dnf makecache; dnf update and switched from kernel - 4.8.6-300 to 4.10.9-200 the server fails to boot... I can't get logs, because I can't login get to an interactive prompt.. the only messages I see on the screen are:

```
[Firmware bug]: The BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 186 is 43003c)
ACPI Error: Field [CDW3] at 96 exceeds Buffer [NULL] size 64 (bits) (20160930/dsopcode-236)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB._OSC] (Node ffffa38274baf50), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20160930/psparse-543)
NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [swapper/01]
```

I found some information regarding the hw-PMU resources, but from what i understand from the HP & RHEL articles, this not the main problem. Also this is my feeling, since I can boot with this error and the 4.8 kernel... I still can't find any useful information regarding the ACPI Error and NMI Watchdog errors.

Any ideas how to fix this one? I hope I can workaround the problem with BIOS change or kernel parameter while booted with the 4.8 kernel...

Comment: Is this fixed in v4.12?

Comment: Hi 0andriy you mean kernel 4.12 ? I have no idea - after last dnf update the server died completely, so will need to play with it someday... quite disappointing situation.. Regards, pavel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=616449)

> HP's \SB._OSC method violates the ACPI spec. \SB._OSC is documented
>   as taking an 8-byte argument, while the HP firmware is attempting to
>   interpret it as a 12-byte one. HP have ignored the spec for this
>   method and implemented their own as part of the Processor Clocking
>   Control specification. We can't work around this without risking
>   breaking spec-compliant machines. Nothing will actually be broken as a
>   result of this error.